# allowRedirectInIframe set true MSAL is not working

Tags: azure, authentication, msal.js

Iframe azure login is not working even though set  ****allowRedirectInIframe: true***. Here my try.

**MSALconfig**

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "e440b5e5-3c66-43c0-8ab5-31a747c2377e",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", 
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/"

  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    secureCookies: false,
  },
  system: {       

    allowRedirectInIframe: true,
  },
  telemetry: {
    application: {
      appName: "My Application",
      appVersion: "1.0.0",
    },
  },
};
```

**Error**
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowRedirectInIframe` is a flag that controls whether MSAL.js will throw an error when `loginRedirect/acquireTokenRedirect` is called in an iframe (which is done to prevent the error message you observe). It does not control whether AAD will still prevent the login page from being displayed in an iframe.

Your application will need to use popup interaction when rendered in an iframe instead.